# Двойной указатель C++: как с ним работать?

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть у нас двойной указатель `char **t;`
Логически предположил что если `char* t1=new char[2];` работает, то и `char **t=new *char[2];` будет работать, но увы оказалось не так. Так все-таки, как расширять под него память и может ли двойной указатель содержать массив указателей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Выделять память подобным образом можно, по поводу того, насколько это красиво, можно попробовать порассуждать, зная подробнее вашу задачу.

   `char **t = new char*[2];`
2. Использовать указатель на указатель для организации массива указателей можно, только следует не забывать, что, помимо выделения памяти под массив указателей, вам потребуется выделить память и под каждый элемент массива.

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Все понятно!

Comment: Не за что, но советую не принимать ответы слишком быстро. Пусть накопится какое-то количество точек зрения. Во-первых, предложенный быстро ответ может оказаться неверным, во-вторых, несколько ответов, дополняя друг друга, могут помочь составить более полное представление о методах решения поставленной задачи.

Comment: Хорошо! Кстати, впопыхах забыл спросить, а освобождение памяти под такой массив реализуется операцией delete[] t;?

Comment: Только не забудьте перед этим, освободить выделенную под элементы память.

Comment: ну это логично)

Answer (score 0):

Добавил бы:

"Логически предположил..." - не логично!

**Для любого типа T тип T* означает «указатель на объект типа Т»**